# How to return PartialView with model from custom AuthorizeAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-partialview, authorize-attribute

At the core of what I'm doing, what I would like is if you go to www.mysite.com/admin/index I want to render a partial view that shows "Unauthorized" that has a Model attached to it.  I was really not wanting the site to show www.mysite.com/error/unauthorized/ as that is not very useful when someone calls up and tells me I got an error on "/error/unauthorized" page, when I really want them to say "I got an unauthorized error on /admin/index page".

I have my CustomAuthorizeAttribute that inherits from AuthorizeAttribute working just fine, other than the redirect.

```
protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
{
    // returns boolean if it is good or not
}
```

Then I have my HandleUnauthorizedRequest and this is where I need to pass in a partial with a model:

```
if (context.RequestContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(context);

}
else
{
    var viewResult = new PartialViewResult();
    viewResult.ViewName = "~/Views/Shared/Unauthorized.cshtml";
    viewResult.Model = new ViewModels.Unauthorized() { MyData = "My Data" }; // obviously can't do this as it is read-only

    context.Result = viewResult;
}
```

I know I can remove viewResult.Model and just use the ViewBag, but I was *really* hoping there was some way to pass in a model to the Partial

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since [`PartialViewResult.Model`](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/ViewResultBase.cs) is get only and returns `ViewData.Model`, all you have to do is to create and set the `ViewData` property:

```
var model = new ViewModels.Unauthorized() { MyData = "My Data" };
var viewResult = new PartialViewResult
{
    ViewName = "~/Views/Shared/Unauthorized.cshtml",
    ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary(model)
};
context.Result = viewResult;
```